# Working wih PHP Coupon Site Script: Redirect error in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, wamp

I am working with coupon script in php. In this i have to redirect my url 127.0.0.1/couponsite/go/1 to www.ebay.com and what is happening is 127.0.0.1/couponsite/go/1 redirected to 127.0.0.1/couponsite/go/1/www.ebay.com
where 1 is mapped with www.ebay.com
similarly 2 is mapped with www.someotherweb.com like this.

So i want to know in which part of my script is the error? I need help regarding this. Hope its not related to .htaccess in anyway. i have a file out.php which is handling all redirect. posting the code of out.php below.

```
<?php

    if ( intval ( $qstring[1] ) < 0 )
        exit( "No coupon selected." );

    if ( $web == "Website" )
    {
        $web = $data->select ( "Website" , "*" , array ( "WebsiteID" => intval ( $qstring[1] ) ) ) ;
        $web = $web[0] ;

        if ( ! empty ( $web ) )
        {
            $data->update ( "Website" , array ( "Views" => intval ( $web["Views"] ) + 1 ) , array ( "WebsiteID" => intval ( $web["WebsiteID"] ) ) ) ;
            header ( "location:".$web["AffilateURL"] ) ;
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            exit ( "Website not found. " ) ;
        }
    }
    elseif ( $tag == "Tag" )
    {
        $offer_id = $qstring[1] ;

        $offer = $data->select ( "Tag_Offers" , "*" , array ( "Tag_OffersID" => intval ( $offer_id ) ) ) ;
        $offer = $offer[0] ;
        if ( ! empty ( $offer ) )
        {
            header ( "location:".$offer["LandingPage"] ) ;
            exit ( ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            exit ( "Offer not found" ) ;
        }
    }
    elseif ( $tag == "WOffer" )
    {
        $offer_id = $qstring[1] ;

        $offer = $data->select ( "Website_Offers" , "*" , array ( "Website_OffersID" => intval ( $offer_id ) ) ) ;
        $offer = $offer[0] ;
        if ( ! empty ( $offer ) )
        {
            header ( "location:".$offer["LandingPage"] ) ;
            exit ( ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            exit ( "Offer not found" ) ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $coupon_id = $qstring[1] ;

        $coupon = $data->select ( "Coupon" , "*" , array ( "CouponID" => intval ( $qstring[1] ) ) ) ;
        $coupon = $coupon[0] ;
        if ( ! empty ( $coupon ) )
        {
            $web = $data->select ( "Website" , "*" , array ( "WebsiteID" => intval ( $coupon["WebsiteID"] ) ) ) ;
            $web = $web[0] ;

            if ( ! empty ( $web ) )
            {
                $data->update ( "Website" , array ( "Views" => intval ( $web["Views"] ) + 1 ) , array ( "WebsiteID" => intval ( $coupon["WebsiteID"] ) ) ) ;
                header ( "location:".$web["AffilateURL"] ) ;
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                exit ( "Website not found." ) ;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            exit ( "Coupon not found." ) ;
        }
    }

?>
```

Additional information: I am using Wamp

Comment: who ever wrote this isn't a good php developer. empty() is evil

Comment: it would be great if you answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a protocol ("http://") before the address.

Comment: like this? header ( "location:" "http://.$offer["LandingPage"]" ) ;
or 
header ( "location: http://.$offer["LandingPage"]" ) ;

Comment: header('Location: http://' . $offer['LandingPage']); ought to work.  That or just make sure that $offer['LandingPage'] has the protocol in it ("http://www.ebay.com/whatever").